# Is it required to change filesystem before installing Ubuntu in a Windows System

Tags: 16.04

I have a Windows system right now and I want to replace it with Ubuntu. I made a bootable USB using Rufus. Now I want to know if I need to change the filesystem from NTFS that is used for windows to FAT32 before installing Ubuntu over it or its done during installation. I don't want to corrupt my hard disk in any case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu on USB or on a harddrive in your PC? Corruption is a term used for filesystems. If you want to install a new OS on your PC, replacing the old one, I do not understand what your worries regarding file system corruption are.The disk will be partitioned and the partitions formated during installation. This process will override your windows installation. Linux does not use FAT32 as a filesystem either.

Comment: As @Bruni says, reformatting is part of the installation. You MUST disable Windows Fast Boot before starting the Ubuntu install. You MIGHT need to disable Secure Boot, depending upon your system. The rest is handled by the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Thanks, @Bruni..I didn't have any idea about that because previously I had installed Linus on a windows machine without any worries.. but somebody poked me with this question when I did this time.. :)